# Is there any unique item to get from minigames?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

Usually, when you pretty much perfect a minigame in a Zelda game, you get some unique item (talking about something that is not Rupees, often it's a piece of heart).

In Breath of the Wild, these items do not exist. So is there anything unique to get from MiniGames (like snow bowling) or is it just Rupees?

Comment: I don't know about all mini-games, but some offer things like horse equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few MiniGames that you can acquire horse armor, and sometimes certain arrows, but besides that, I'm not too sure.

Comment: Snow Bowling gives you a Blizzard Rod for your first perfect score. I'd say that's relatively unique, although not "unique unique".